# Using a console application to host WCF endpoints that expose asp.net ProfileService, ProfileService and RoleService

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership, console-application

I've got an MVC web application that is used as an interface to a Console based app that exposes a bunch of ServiceHost/s using the net.pipe protocol.

I would like to use the asp.net membership/role/profile provider to manage my users and their roles and profile information (Inside the Console Application). I've done this in quite a few apps, but normally I reference these providers directly from the web application itself.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515342%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is a good walk-through on doing pretty much what I would like, except I don't want to host the WCF service endpoints in IIS, but inside my console app - which will eventually become a windows service. When I try and host the ServiceHost through my console application I get the following error:

```
This service requires ASP.NET compatibility and must be hosted in IIS.  
Either host the service in IIS with ASP.NET compatibility turned on in 
web.config or set the
AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute.AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode 
property to a value other than Required.
```

Now it seems that I won't be able to set that property to anything other than Required.

I've tried another route which is using the wrapper class/interface defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019264/is-there-a-wcf-service-to-sit-on-top-of-aspnet-membership-and-provide-login-creat) for my authentication service, which I managed to get wired into in my MVC app without too much trouble, but this doesn't cover my Authorisation (using roles) or profile needs.

Has anyone got a solution to this, <strike>I can't be the only one trying to do this</strike>? [I'm not](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/edc06e7f-ede0-4b94-9852-4d2995258f64)